# Installed New GPU and now I get a black screen

Tags: graphics-card, gpu

I decided to get new gpu, replacing my amd radeon 6850 for a  nvidia geforce gtx 1650.
After the installation, the pc boots, I get the motherboard initial screen but it doesn’t go past that. Non-responsive, can’t access Bios. I do get a bleep, screen goes black. Then another bleep like 5 seconds apart, the motherboard screens shows with some glitch line on the top, bleeps again and it goes black again, with the bleep continuing every 5 seconds or so.
I’ve used ddu, disabled onboard graphics, don’t know what else to try. Hope someone here can help me as I haven’t seen those details I described at other forums where people had similar problems.
My psu is 650w, 16gb RAM, cpu is intel i7 (can’t remember specifics) and motherboard is compatible gigabyte ga-z77-d3h.

An interesting development (at least for me). I decided to boot the computer with gpu on but no power supply. So it pretty much happened the same thing, so I am wondering of it’s a psu issue. Nvidia says the psu needs to be 350w or greater. Mine is 650w, so I guess I have some to spare. The cable is fine as I had switched back to my amd one and it worked. I thought the power was alright as the fan was spinning, but I guess that can be done just via the motherboard. Well, I hope that extra piece of info helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All sorted. In the end all I had to do was update my Bios. New gpu installed and running!

Answer (score 0):

I actually came through this session when I installed GPU then a black screen was before me. Then I applied these tips to resolve the issue:

turn off and unplug the pc
remove graphic card
plug monitor into video output
trun on PC
click on start and then type "msconfig"
select the boot tab and click on box
apply then ok
don't resatrt
shutdown and unplug
install graphic card
turn on pc
go to device manager
expand display adapter
diable graphic card (do not uninstall)
click start button and type "msconfig"
unclick the safe boot
then restart

Almost it will help you fix out your problem